# Prove that the given family is a topology on $A$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ a top. space and $A \subseteq X$. Consider $\mathcal{T}_{A}=\{\mathbf{U} \cup V :\mathbf{U}\in \tau \hspace{0.1cm} \text{y} \hspace{0.1cm} V\subseteq A\}$. Proof that $\mathcal{T}_{A}$ is a topology over A.

Try the following

1. Note that as $\tau$ is a topology over $X$, then $\emptyset \in \tau$ and thus $\emptyset \subseteq A$, if i take $\mathbf{U}=\emptyset=V$ then $\emptyset=\mathbf{U} \cup V$, this means $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$.

   On the other hand, note that as $\tau$ is a topology over $X$ we have that $X\in \mathcal{T}$ and if $V\subseteq A$ thus by hipotesis $V \subseteq A \subseteq X$, i.e. $V \subseteq X$ so $X=X \cup V=X \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$.
2. Let $\{C_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ an arbitrary non-empty collection of $\mathcal{T}_{A}$.
   Since $C_{i} \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$, for all $i\in I$, then $C_{i}=\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{j}$, where $\mathbf{U}_{i}\in \mathcal{T }$ and $V_{j}\subseteq A$ ($i, j \in I$) with which

   $$\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}=\bigcup_{i, j\in I} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup  V_{j}\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcup_{j\in I} V_{j}$$

Since $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology for $X$ then $\bigcup U_{i} \in \mathcal{T}$ and since $V_{j} \subseteq A$, for all $j\in I $, so $\bigcup V_{j} \subseteq A$, so $\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i} \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$.

3. Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be a non-empty finite collection of $\mathcal{T}_{A}$.
   Since $C_{i}\in \mathcal{T}_{A}$, for all $i\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, then $C_{i}=\mathbf{U}_ {i} \cup V_{j}$, where $\mathbf{U}_{i}\in \mathcal{T}$ and $V_{j}\subseteq A$ (for all $i, j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$) so

   $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} C_{i}=\bigcap_{i, j= 1}^{n} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{j}\right)=\bigcap_{i= 1}^{n}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} V_{j}$$

   Similarly, since $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology for $X$ then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_{i} \in \tau$ and since $\bigcap_{j=1} ^{n} V_{j} \subseteq V_{j} \subseteq A$, for all $j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, then $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} V_{j} \subseteq A$, so by the definition of $\mathcal{T}_{A}$, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} C_{i} \in \mathcal{T} A$

Is there anything I can improve on this, any suggestions? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both (2) and (3), you have a notational issue:  When you define $C_i = \mathbf{U}_i \cup V_j$, this is arguably nonsense.  It should be $C_i = \mathbf{U}_i \cup V_i$.

In step (2), if you propagate this change, it fixes everything.  You have

> Let $\{C_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ an arbitrary non-empty collection of $\mathcal{T}_{A}$. Since $C_{i} \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$, for all $i\in I$, then $C_{i}=\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}$, where $\mathbf{U}_{i}\in \mathcal{T}$ and $V_{i}\subseteq A$ ($i \in I$) with which
> $$\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i}=\bigcup_{i\in I} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup  V_{i}\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcup_{j\in I} V_{j}$$
>
> Since $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology for $X$ then $\bigcup U_{i} \in \mathcal{T}$ and since $V_{j} \subseteq A$, for all $j\in I $, so $\bigcup V_{j} \subseteq A$, so $\bigcup_{i\in I} C_{i} \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$.

In step (3), there's a greater error.  We can try to make the same change, giving

> Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be a non-empty finite collection of $\mathcal{T}_{A}$.  Since $C_{i}\in \mathcal{T}_{A}$, for all $i\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, then $C_{i}=\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}$, where $\mathbf{U}_{i}\in \mathcal{T}$ and $V_{i}\subseteq A$ (for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$) so
> $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} C_{i}=\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}\right)=\bigcap_{i= 1}^{n}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} V_{j}$$

but now we've already run into an error that notational change doesn't fix:
$$\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}\right)=\bigcap_{i= 1}^{n}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} V_{j}$$
is not necessarily true.  I considered, given what you write next, that you may have intended
$$\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n} \left( \mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}\right)=\bigcap_{i= 1}^{n}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} V_{j}$$
but this is also not necessarily true.

If you write something true and useful, you would need to instead write
$$\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n} \left(\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup V_{i}\right) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \left(\mathbf{U}_i \cup (\mathbf{U}_i \cap A) \cup V_i\right) = \bigcap_{i= 1}^{n}\mathbf{U}_{i} \cup \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} ((\mathbf{U}_j\cap A) \cup V_{j})$$
but now you'd need to prove this identity. [Feel free to prove this equality if you want, or you can read on for a simpler method]

*Instead*, it would be easier to just show that
$$(\mathbf{U}_1 \cup V_1) \cap (\mathbf{U}_2 \cup V_2) = (\mathbf{U}_1 \cap \mathbf{U}_2) \cup \left((\mathbf{U}_1 \cap V_2) \cup (V_1 \cap \mathbf{U}_2 ) \cup (V_1 \cap V_2)\right) \in \mathcal{T}_A$$
A straight-forward induction shows that any non-empty finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{T}_A$ is also in $\mathcal{T}_A$, without having to deal with the $n$ elements explicitly.